# Manager did not give clear answer when I asked for a day off

Tags: management, united-states, new-job, time-off

I recently started a new job. I asked my manager if I could take a day off next week for a family obligation. He said I hadn't been with the company long enough to use my vacation time. I found this a bit odd as I could have just called in sick with no notice. He said we could work something out where I'd make it up. He also mentioned something about not wanting to do paper work. I find my manager difficult to communicate with. In situations like this one I felt there was no conclusion to my request. (Any general advice on how to work with manager's who are bad at making sense?) I spoke with another new hire who reports to the same manager and he said he was told the same thing.

I looked at my contract and it said I was entitled to vacation days and sick leave, but did not specify the amount or details. I red the group policy document that it refers to and it too specified no details. I then spoke to HR who said there is no such rule and I just need to fill out a vacation form and have my manager sign it.

What should I do now? Should I have mentioned I do not need to be paid for the time I take off? In general do companies make a distinction between sick days and vacation days? Obviously there are other times someone may need to be absent from work, some planned and some not. Is any absence not relating to illness generally considered a vacation day?

Comment: What happened when you filled in the form?

Comment: @ComicSansStrikephim is it normal to fill in a vacation request form for a single day or even half a day?

Comment: @ClanLatin There is no universal rule. All I know about your company policy is what your HR said.

Comment: And perhaps more importantly, it doesn't matter what's "normal", you don't have the power to change it. What's your actual goal here?

Comment: @PhilipKendall maybe I'm out to lunch here but I find it rather rigid that not a single day is allowed off for the first 6 months and that it was never discussed during hiring or on boarding. Again, I didn't really consider a single day off to be a vacation.

Comment: @ClanLatin so if we say to you "that's not normal", what are you going to do? You _could_ go to your manager and say "some nerds on the internet say that's not normal", but I'm not sure that will have much effect other than making your manager think less of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill out the form and hand it to him to get signed and move forwards from there.

Your manager not wanting to do paperwork is not your problem. Just abide by company policy.

The rest of your questions are company specific, only your HR would be able to tell you.

Answer (score 8):

> What should I do now?

> He said we could work something out where I'd make it up.

Clearly, you should talk with your manager and work something out where you'd make it up.

It seems as if you got a clear answer, but perhaps not the answer you wanted.

Comment: I disagree that I got a clear answer, "you're not supposed to but it's possible, you'll just have to make it up" does not seem clear to me. While I certainly do not want to lie, at times like these it seems encouraged: I could have called in sick instead of giving them notice.

Comment: "Make it up" does not mean "invent a lie" it means "take the day off and then work extra at another time so you have worked the expected total hours" You *make up* the working hours you have lost. Talk to your manager.

Answer (score 1):

Making the time up instead of using a vacation/etc day sounds to me like your boss wants you to work late the other 4 days of the week (or whatever your pay/time sheet period is) or work a day on the weekend so you still have 40 hours of work for the week.